# Animation on SupportMapFragment in android

Tags: android, android-support-library

I want to add fade-in and fade-out animation on SupportMapFragment on Button Click. I am not able to do so..! can anybody help me with this situation or guide to tutorial?

Comment: Show us what you've tried first.

Comment: I faced the same problem, as far as I can say, try to do anything that involve effects on a `SupportMapFragment` it's pretty hard, given that is implemented with a `SurfaceView`. The best that I achieved was use a `PagerTabStrip` and make an horizontal sliding menu. Give a try to this example. [PagerExample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Pager)